# Парс стены vk + java

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

К делу. Изучаю api vk. Понял как формировать нужный запрос, а как спарсить это? Ответ приходит следующего вида: [image: ответ]

Нужно только text. 
Есть мысль такая, ответ чешим до сочетания text: ' запоминаем позицию. Чешим до ',
Готово. Но мне кажется это тупо как то. Есть более грамотное решение?

Comment: Абракадабра, которую вы видите, называется JSON. Ну а дальше google://java+parse+json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте библиотеки для работы с Json для Java, например [вот](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).